# "Post method not allowed" error in Tinymce image upload

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tinymce

I am trying to include image upload capacity in my tinymce editor in a vue.js form. When I browse and upload an image, it keeps giving me 405 error.

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Now, I tried using get method for both the form submit route and the image upload route.

```
Route::get('/news-events/store', 'NewsEventsController@storeNewsEvent')->name('admin.news-event-store');
Route::get('/uploadimag-news', 'NewsEventsController@upload');
```

The form submit tag:

```
<form id="addNewNews" action="{{route('admin.news-event-store')}}" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return postForm()">
```

The tinymcr initialization:

```
tinymce.init({
                selector: '#news_content',
                plugins: 'lists,imagetools,image',
                toolbar: 'numlist bullist  undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | link image',
                height: 250,
                image_title: true,
                    automatic_uploads: true,
                   images_upload_url: '/uploadimag-news',
                    file_picker_types: 'image',
                    file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
                        var input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
                        input.onchange = function() {
                            var file = this.files[0];
                            if(Math.round((this.files[0].size/1024)*100/100) > 200){
                                alert('Image size maximum 200KB');
                                return false
                            }else {
                                var reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                                reader.onload = function () {
                                    var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                                    var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                                    var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                                    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                                    blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                                    cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                                };
                            }
                        };
                        input.click();
                    },

                setup: function (editor) {
                    editor.on('change', function () {
                        editor.save();
                    });
                },
                init_instance_callback : function(editor) {
                    var freeTiny = document.querySelector('.tox .tox-notification--in');
                    freeTiny.style.display = 'none';
                },
            });
```

So obviously, there are no post methods here. What gives? Where is my error getting a post method from? And yes, I have tried clearing route cache.

N.B edit: I feel like I should clarify this,but the form was originally a post request and works fine that way. I only changed it to get request because I was concerned it might be interfering with the image upload function. But there is no issue with form submission. Only issue is the image upload function thinks that it is a post route when it clearly is not.

Comment: in form change `method="post"` and route to `Route::post('/news-events/store'`

Comment: Umm......that was how it was in the first place. And that is exactly the issue, post method is NOT allowed for tinymce image upload.

Comment: Why? https://www.dbestech.com/tutorials/easiest-way-to-upload-image-in-laravel

Comment: I got no clue. this is the same thing I am trying to follow, the only thing I changed are the route names and slightly different method. See any issues here?

public function upload(Request $request){
        $fileName=$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        $path=$request->file('file')->storeAs('uploades', $fileName, 'public');
        dd($path);
        return response()->json(['location'=>"$path"]); 
        
        /*$imgpath = request()->file('file')->store('uploads', 'public'); 
        return response()->json(['location' => "/storage/$imgpath"]);*/

    }

Comment: your from action is this `action="{{route('admin.news-event-store')}}"` so probably you should call this function `storeNewsEvent` not `upload()`

Comment: well, as far as I know form submit route and image upload function are separate, but worth a shot I guess. I will get back after trying it out. Thnaks.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your route file and save it like this,

```php
Route::get('/news-events/store', 'NewsEventsController@storeNewsEvent')->name('admin.news-event-store');
Route::post('/uploadimag-news', 'NewsEventsController@upload');
```

by default tinymce send a post request in your provided upload url.

here is the docs of tinymce: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/upload-images/

Comment: nah, it still says the same thing.  The POST method is not supported for this route. What I dont understand is why? Why would post method not be supported for tinymce. It is obviously sending data to controller.

Comment: can you please inspect your request from developer tool, and check the request with header and payload. and also please recompile your js. and also dump the request in your controller method.

Comment: if this `images_upload_url` is not working properly then you may use the custom image upload option by, `images_upload_handler` ex: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/image/#images_upload_handler

Comment: I checked the header. it is definitely sending a post request.
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/uploadimag-news
Request Method: POST

Problem is, even when I define the route as get, it still sends a post req. This might be explained by the fact as you said: 'by default tinymce send a post request in your provided upload url.' Problem is, why might my code not support a post request?

Comment: you can check the error log to get the error from trace back. if it throwing from the routes then check the routes in web.php file properly either if it comes from any middleware then debug on it, or try to use this way and check the request method, payload etc, `Route::any('/uploadimag-news', function(){ dd(request()); })`. and also assure that you did not define same route path. specially after route parameter.

Comment: and one more thing, please run this command in your project directory to clear all the cache, `php artisan optimize:clear`, sometimes laravel cache the routes and new changes is not affect.

Comment: I checked route::any. Still nothing. it is still being treated as a post request. and yes, i tried optimize:clear. And no, I do not have the same route defined anywhere else. I defined the route in VerifyCsrfToken.php to avoid using csrf token issue. I am running out of ideas......

Answer (score 0):

Update your `VerifyCsrToken.php` file.

add the path in except array.

```php
protected $except = [
     //
     '/uploadimag-news',       
];
```

And you route should be post method.
cause tinyMCE send post request to the path.

```php
Route::post('/uploadimag-news', [NewsEventsController::class, 'upload']);
```